# Is an oracle DB constraint implemented via a trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers, constraints

Simple question here: I like to know if a constraint in a oracle database is nothing else like a trigger.

Comment: A `constraint` is not a `trigger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints in Oracle are at a much lower core level than triggers. They are implemented within the engine in C or C++, certainly not in PL/SQL. In addition, they have the added benefit of being included in the database dictionary, providing metadata about what's expected of the data.

Generally speaking, if you are attempting to validate data, it is best to use constraints. Triggers have their uses, but often they are overused for the purpose of "constraints".